# C#: Is it necessary to dispose of a graphics element inside a custom control?

Tags: c#, graphics, custom-controls, gdi+

I've created a custom control, overridden it's paint event. When I try to dispose of the graphics I create they just disappear from the screen. Don't I need to use dispose in custom controls?

**EDIT: I've included a code snippet. Why can't i dispose the dc graphics object, created from the PaintEventArgs? Do i need to dispose it?**

```
class canvas : Control
    {

        PointF mouseDown;

        float newX;
        float newY;
        float zoomFactor = 1F;

        Graphics _dc;

        public canvas()
        {
            this.DoubleBuffered = true;
            mouseDown = new PointF(0F, 0F);
            this.Paint += new PaintEventHandler(ctrl_Paint);
        }

        private void ctrl_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {


            Graphics dc = e.Graphics;
            _dc = dc;

            dc.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;

            Color gridColor = Color.FromArgb(230, 230, 230);
            Pen gridPen = new Pen(gridColor, 1);

            float offX = (float)((Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(newX, 2)) % (30 * zoomFactor)));
            float offY = (float)((Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(newY, 2)) % (30 * zoomFactor)));

            for (float y = offY; y < this.Height; y = y + 30 * zoomFactor)
            {
                dc.DrawLine(gridPen, 0, y, this.Width, y);
            }
            for (float x = offX; x < this.Width; x = x + 30 * zoomFactor)
            {
                dc.DrawLine(gridPen, x, 0, x, this.Height);
            }

            dc.TranslateTransform(newX, newY);
            dc.ScaleTransform(zoomFactor, zoomFactor, MatrixOrder.Prepend);

            float XPosition = 10;
            float YPosition = 10;
            float CornerRadius = 5;
            float Width = 50;
            float Height = 50;

            Color BoxColor = Color.FromArgb(0, 0, 0);
            Pen BoxPen = new Pen(BoxColor, 2);

            GraphicsPath Path = new GraphicsPath();

            Path.AddLine(XPosition + CornerRadius, YPosition, XPosition + Width - (CornerRadius * 2), YPosition);
            Path.AddArc(XPosition + Width - (CornerRadius * 2), YPosition, CornerRadius * 2, CornerRadius * 2, 270, 90);
            Path.AddLine(XPosition + Width, YPosition + CornerRadius, XPosition + Width, YPosition + Height - (CornerRadius * 2));
            Path.AddArc(XPosition + Width - (CornerRadius * 2), YPosition + Height - (CornerRadius * 2), CornerRadius * 2, CornerRadius * 2, 0, 90);
            Path.AddLine(XPosition + Width - (CornerRadius * 2), YPosition + Height, XPosition + CornerRadius, YPosition + Height);
            Path.AddArc(XPosition, YPosition + Height - (CornerRadius * 2), CornerRadius * 2, CornerRadius * 2, 90, 90);
            Path.AddLine(XPosition, YPosition + Height - (CornerRadius * 2), XPosition, YPosition + CornerRadius);
            Path.AddArc(XPosition, YPosition, CornerRadius * 2, CornerRadius * 2, 180, 90);

            Path.CloseFigure();

            dc.DrawPath(BoxPen, Path);

            LinearGradientBrush lgb = new LinearGradientBrush(new PointF(XPosition + (Width / 2), YPosition), new PointF(XPosition + (Width / 2), YPosition + Height), Color.RosyBrown, Color.Red);

            dc.FillPath(lgb, Path);

        }
}
```

Comment: Could you post a code snippet? In a paint event, you don't have to create your own Graphics instance, but rather get it from the event.

Comment: This should be winforms, right?

Comment: I've edit'ed the question and included a code snippet.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you did not create the graphics object you should not dispose it, so if you function signature is `protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)` you would NOT dispose e.Graphics.

However if you create a graphics object in the OnPaint handler you will need to dispose it.

General rule of thumb (and it is a rule of thumb not a law) if you did not get your object from a `Graphics.FromXxxxx()` you do not need to call Dispose.

**EDIT to reflect code you have posted**

You do not need to dispose of the Grapics object because it was passed to you as a argument, however you are not actually overriding the paint event for your controll. This is the correct way to do it.

```
class canvas : Control
    {

        PointF mouseDown;

        float newX;
        float newY;
        float zoomFactor = 1F;


        public canvas()
        {
            this.DoubleBuffered = true;
            mouseDown = new PointF(0F, 0F);
        }

        protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnPaint(e);
            Graphics dc = e.Graphics;

            dc.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;

            Color gridColor = Color.FromArgb(230, 230, 230);
            Pen gridPen = new Pen(gridColor, 1);

            float offX = (float)((Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(newX, 2)) % (30 * zoomFactor)));
            float offY = (float)((Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(newY, 2)) % (30 * zoomFactor)));

            for (float y = offY; y < this.Height; y = y + 30 * zoomFactor)
            {
                dc.DrawLine(gridPen, 0, y, this.Width, y);
            }
            for (float x = offX; x < this.Width; x = x + 30 * zoomFactor)
            {
                dc.DrawLine(gridPen, x, 0, x, this.Height);
            }

            dc.TranslateTransform(newX, newY);
            dc.ScaleTransform(zoomFactor, zoomFactor, MatrixOrder.Prepend);

            float XPosition = 10;
            float YPosition = 10;
            float CornerRadius = 5;
            float Width = 50;
            float Height = 50;

            Color BoxColor = Color.FromArgb(0, 0, 0);
            Pen BoxPen = new Pen(BoxColor, 2);

            GraphicsPath Path = new GraphicsPath();

            Path.AddLine(XPosition + CornerRadius, YPosition, XPosition + Width - (CornerRadius * 2), YPosition);
            Path.AddArc(XPosition + Width - (CornerRadius * 2), YPosition, CornerRadius * 2, CornerRadius * 2, 270, 90);
            Path.AddLine(XPosition + Width, YPosition + CornerRadius, XPosition + Width, YPosition + Height - (CornerRadius * 2));
            Path.AddArc(XPosition + Width - (CornerRadius * 2), YPosition + Height - (CornerRadius * 2), CornerRadius * 2, CornerRadius * 2, 0, 90);
            Path.AddLine(XPosition + Width - (CornerRadius * 2), YPosition + Height, XPosition + CornerRadius, YPosition + Height);
            Path.AddArc(XPosition, YPosition + Height - (CornerRadius * 2), CornerRadius * 2, CornerRadius * 2, 90, 90);
            Path.AddLine(XPosition, YPosition + Height - (CornerRadius * 2), XPosition, YPosition + CornerRadius);
            Path.AddArc(XPosition, YPosition, CornerRadius * 2, CornerRadius * 2, 180, 90);

            Path.CloseFigure();

            dc.DrawPath(BoxPen, Path);

            LinearGradientBrush lgb = new LinearGradientBrush(new PointF(XPosition + (Width / 2), YPosition), new PointF(XPosition + (Width / 2), YPosition + Height), Color.RosyBrown, Color.Red);

            dc.FillPath(lgb, Path);

        }
}
```

I also removed `_dc` as you should not be editing the Graphics object when you are not inside the OnPaint function.

Answer (score 0):

Without an example it's hard to say exactly where the phoblem is, but I can guess:

In your overriden OnPaint event, there's a parameter PaintEventArgs. You should perform all drawing onto this parameter's Graphics object, and you're good to go. That should make your graphics stick.

Comment: I've included example-code in the question. I do paint onto the parameter's Graphics object. But earlier when i drew upon for example a panel i had to dispose the graphics in order to prevent memory leaks. My question is: Is this neccesary/possible when using a custom control as the one i've created?

Answer (score -1):

You should be disposing any controls within your custom control that implement the `IDisposable` interface. Ensure that your custom control implements this interface as well (add an implementation of the `Dispose()` method) so that you dispose of the controls within it properly (calling their `Dispose()` methods).

Comment: You should NOT dispose objects that are not your responsibility to dispose. Overriding `OnPaint(e)` you would **not** dispose `dc` if you did `var dc = e.Graphics` (which is exactly what the OP did).

Comment: I specifically stated that controls should be disposed, not all objects. The OP's control should implement `IDisposable` so that any of the control's members are disposed properly. There is no need to dispose of anything in the `OnPaint()` method.

Comment: The answer alludes to an incorrect answer as the question is asking *"should I dispose the Graphics object"*. You do clarify in a comment, but that simply makes the answer completely irrelevant and not even addressing the question. This question has nothing to do with disposing controls.