# Using e.Graphics – when Using statement is needed?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, winforms

A beginner question... but despite studying I'm not sure about how **System.Drawing.Graphics** works. Does it *always* need presence of `using` statement even if e.Graphics was supplied to me? I already know about Q/A [When do I need to use dispose on Graphics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3171185/when-do-i-need-to-use-dispose-on-graphics).

In other words: in the following example, can C#/VB `Using` statement be safely omitted?

```vb
Private Sub MyControl_Paint(sender As Object, e As PaintEventArgs) Handles MyBase.Paint
    Using e.Graphics
        e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(...)
        ControlPaint.DrawFocusRectangle(e.Graphics, ...)
    End Using
End Sub
```

Comment: @Sinatr That question is slightly unrelated. This is more related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4316149/613130 and the answer is no, because you didn't create it.

Comment: It's worth highlighting the comment below the accepted answer to that question: "do not dispose an object you didn't create. Disposing e.Graphics is a nasty latent bug"

Comment: @usr – question clarified - please review. Now duplicate question is not closely related.

Comment: @miroxlav The answer is clearly written in is comment (that is a direct quote from Hans: *do not dispose an object you didn't create. Disposing e.Graphics is a nasty latent bug*). So the answer is "the `using` *must* be removed"

Comment: @xanatos – yes :)   so either let's change duplicate link to that answer or I can delete the entire question. May I ask you what do you recommend?